# How to use Goto statement in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have written **jquery** code to dictate a list of English words respectively.
I used HTML audio "on ended" event to pronounce the next word as demonstrated in the following code.

```
$("#PlaySnd").on('ended', function(e) {
  // start:
  var crnt = $("img[src$='../Images/checked.png']");
  crnt.closest('tr').next().find('.chck').attr('src', '../Images/checked.png');
  crnt.attr('src', '../Images/Unchecked.png');
  crnt = $("img[src$='../Images/checked.png']");
  var thisword = crnt.parent().parent().children(0).children(0).html();
  if (/\s/.test(thisword)) {
    //alert('it has space');
    // here I would like to start code from the bigenning like this 
    // GoTo stat
    // because some words hase more than one word so it causes progrm stop so I need to move to the next one 
  } else {
    $("#PlaySnd").attr('src', 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/oxford/' + thisword + '--_gb_1.mp3').trigger('play');
  } // end if
});
```

as demonstrated in the comments I need to do something like VBA "**GoTo**" in order to proceed the program and prevent stopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `goto` statement in js, but there are some workarounds. Using a labeled while works pretty good I think:

```
$("#PlaySnd").on('ended', function (e) { 
   start: while(true) {
     var crnt = $("img[src$='../Images/checked.png']");
     crnt.closest('tr').next().find('.chck').attr('src', '../Images/checked.png');
     crnt.attr('src', '../Images/Unchecked.png');
     crnt = $("img[src$='../Images/checked.png']");
     var thisword = crnt.parent().parent().children(0).children(0).html();
     if (/\s/.test(thisword)) {
        //alert('it has space');
        // here I would like to start code from the bigenning like this 
        continue start
        // because some words hase more than one word so it causes progrm stop so I need to move to the next one 
     }
     else {
         $("#PlaySnd").attr('src', 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/oxford/' + thisword + '--_gb_1.mp3').trigger('play');
     } // end if
     break; // break when reaching end
   } // end start labeled while
 });
```

Comment: Yes this works, but still the use of `label` is to be discouraged, IMHO. In fact this code runs exactly the same if you remove `start:` and change `continue start` to `continue;`. You can then omit the `continue` if you put the `break;` inside the `else`-branch. Then you can invert the `if()`-condition and put the `else`-code in the `if()`-branch. So much to improve - again, IMHO.

Comment: @Peter B - I know, there's much to improve, but I wanted to give him something that is closest semantically to a goto statement in other languages. I added the label to make it more general in case you have another loop inside. Of couse, there can be made improvements

Comment: @Peter B - yes, brother, I got it. but I did not invert `if()` because I need to but some handles. As I requested in this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758308/how-can-i-fix-the-problems-of-english-words-pronunciation-link-using-jquery)